# Union/Intersection data visualization - javascript preferred

Tags: javascript, jquery, data-visualization

I am in the process of building a web application and have been tasked with building a pretty tricky visual requirement.

I need a way to display visual representations of entities in circles.  Just like in math 101, i also need to visually represent their union and intersections.

Like this image..
http://www.k12math.com/math-concepts/sets/A_and_B_and_C_un_int.png

So for example, let's say I have three circles on my canvas that represent 3 programming languages like java, c++, and perl.

If I want to see what object oriented languages exist in my canvas, I would need the java and c++ circles to intersect.

I would prefer some sort of Jquery plugin rather than doing this from scratch.

Also, the circles representing the data entities should not be limited to 3.  There can be n number or circles.

If I was forced to do it from scratch, some suggestions on how to approach it would be appreciated.

Also, the circles should be draggable.  If I wanted to remove perl from my canvas, I should be able to just drag it into a trash can.
Feel free to comment for questions and/or clarifications.

One last thing, each section of the circles should be clickable.  In otherwords, if I click on the object oriented intersection, I should fire an event that fetches languages that are object oriented.

Comment: A Venn diagram seems close - a ready-to-use solution for creating those is the Google Chart API: http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/docs/gallery/venn_charts.html.

Comment: you want venn diagrams. Check out google charting and you can use this http://keith-wood.name/gChart.html, also if you need to do it yourself still, check out http://raphaeljs.com/, this will allow you to draw vectors, so that should make it easier.

Comment: Looks promising, do you think I would be able to hook dragging and dropping of circles?

Answer (score 1):

If you want dragging then the Google Chart API does not suffice since it provides a static image. Instead, you can use `<canvas>` combined with its `globalCompositeOperation` to set what should happen when they intersect (`"lighter"` adds the values): http://jsfiddle.net/eGjak/226/.

This solution does use jQuery for convenience. It does not show languages when you click, but this code may be a start for what you're trying to implement.

```
var ctx = $('#cv').get(0).getContext('2d');
var pi2 = Math.PI * 2;

ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter";
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.25)"; // semi-transparent color

var Circle = function(x, y, r) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.r = r;
};

var circles = [
    new Circle(100, 100, 50),
    new Circle(200, 200, 75),
    new Circle(200, 100, 25)
];

function iterate(f) { // convenience function
    for(var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
        f.call(circles[i], i, circles[i]);
    }
}

function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 400);

    iterate(function() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, pi2);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();
    });
}

var sqrt = Math.sqrt;
var selected;

function coords(e) {
    var o = $('#cv').offset(),
        x = e.pageX - o.left,
        y = e.pageY - o.top;

    return {x: x, y: y};
}

var grab; // to save grab offset from middle of selected circle

$("#cv").mousedown(function(e) {
    var c = coords(e);
    grab = c;

    iterate(function() {
        var dx = this.x - c.x,
            dy = this.y - c.y;

        if(sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy) < this.r) { // mouse within this circle
            selected = this;
            grab.x -= this.x;
            grab.y -= this.y;
        }
    });
}).mousemove(function(e) {
    var c = coords(e);

    if(selected) {
        selected.x = c.x - grab.x;
        selected.y = c.y - grab.y;
        draw();
    }
}).mouseup(function() {
    selected = null;
});

draw();
```

Comment: Awesome...I took a look at this, and the code is really clean...i'm going to play around with it a bit more to see how to capture when a user clicks on an area on the circle, and whether or not they clicked on an intersection